# Create a Manga App

Tags: android, c++

I've asked this before but apparently I was too broad on my description so i'll give it a try again. I'm using a library from Flandmark to actually use facial recognition of a person - figure out where their eyes, nose and mouth are. After that want I want to do is to generate a manga image of the person. I'm not sure how to do this. The first way I thought of was using a large database of manga images of specific areas such as the eyes, and map them to the original image. Question is, is there a way I can make the image look like a manga image in terms of background, colours, etc.

The first thing I thought would be useful is to get the size of the eyes and width of the mouth. This is done using this part of the Flandmark code:

```
       flandmark_detect(input, bbox, model, landmarks);

       // display landmarks
       cvRectangle(orig, cvPoint(bbox[0], bbox[1]), cvPoint(bbox[2], bbox[3]), CV_RGB(255,0,0) );
       cvRectangle(orig, cvPoint(model->bb[0], model->bb[1]), cvPoint(model->bb[2], model->bb[3]), CV_RGB(0,0,255) );
       cvCircle(orig, cvPoint((int)landmarks[0], (int)landmarks[1]), 3, CV_RGB(0, 0,255), CV_FILLED);

       for (int i = 2; i < 2*model->data.options.M; i += 2)
       {
            cvCircle(orig, cvPoint(int(landmarks[i]), int(landmarks[i+1])), 3, CV_RGB(255,0,0), CV_ED);
       }
```

Any help would be appreciated as I don't know the best way to do this and im really stuck. Thanks

Comment: you could take color samples from regions of the face and then flat shade those areas, or create a gradual transition between colors, then at the end use edge detection matrix to draw the line art, or you could draw the line art first which would probably produce better results

Comment: How would I draw the line art?

Comment: using an edge detection filter see http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SobelEdgeDetectionFilter/ for examples

Comment: you reckon this is going to end up looking manga-ish?...

Comment: no, you use the edge detection to find the edges, you then fill the edges with blank, then you take the image grab color samples from the different facial zones, pick light, dark and mid tones then create a gradient to smooth out the coloring, this should provide a flat shade effect

Comment: sorry meant to say 'fill in the edges with black'

Comment: Yeah... question is how on earth am i going to do that in C++...